# Preparing a former master to run as slave again

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have a streaming replication setup using postgresql 9.3. I have two servers, the master (server_1) and the slave (server_2).

The other day I did a failover to my slave (server_2). Now server_2 has been running as master for a couple of days, and I have now setup my primary master (server_1) again, and it now runs as master. I would like to avoid reinstalling server_2 before turning it into a slave of server_1 again. How can I do that? What dir's should I delete etc, in order to have a "clean" server that I can use as slave again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only officially supported method is to make a new base backup, or:

- pg_start_backup() on the new master
- rsync from new master to old master
- pg_stop_backup()
- ensure WAL got copied over and applied
- create recovery.conf
- start resynced server

The 3rd party tool [`pg_rewind`](https://github.com/vmware/pg_rewind) is intended for that purpose. I haven't worked with it as yet and can't vouch for it in production.

Comment: Sure, but don't I have to "delete" the old cluster from the to-be-slave, before I start doing the above?

Comment: @NielsKristian If you use pg_basebackup, yes. If you use rsync, no, because rsync can incrementally update it.

Comment: I see, that was actually the answer I was looking for! Thank you Craig, you are one of the most helpful persons I can think of :-)